# Partial string search and distinct

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
questions = await _database.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<QuestionEntry>(x =>
    x.Card.ToUpper() == "Y" &&
    matchYear(x.Years, year) &&
    x.Subject == subject);

result =  (from question in questions
select question.Topic).Distinct().ToList();
```

`x.Years` is in the form of "1,2,3" and year includes a single digit such as "2". I tried function `matchYear()` that matches comma separated values but it seems not possible to use custom functions in filter expression. Error message:

> no such function: matchyear in "select * from "QuestionEntry" where ((((upper("Card")) = ?) and matchyear("Years",?)) and ("Subject" = ?))"

How to do this within the query definition (either as a search in comma separated values, or a partial string match)? And how can I incorporate `distinct()` into the filter instead of doing it after getting all the values? I need to return a list of topics.

Comment: Found `.Contains()` but still wondering if there is a way to incorporate distinct into the query.